# Why doesn't ResolveAll<T> get the default (not-named) registration? Why only named registrations and mappings?

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, unity-container, ioc-container

If you did this:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();

            container.RegisterType<IService, DataService>();
            container.RegisterType<IService, LoggingService>("Logging");
            container.RegisterType<IService, CachingService>("Caching");

            var services = container.ResolveAll<IService>();

            foreach (var service in services)
                Console.WriteLine(service);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    interface IService { }
    class DataService : IService { }
    class LoggingService : IService { }
    class CachingService : IService { }
```

The output you would get would include only the named mappings and would not include the default `DataService` mapping. The output of this program would be:

```
MoreUnityPractice.LoggingService
MoreUnityPractice.CachingService
```

Why did they decide not to get the default, unnamed mapping/registration with `ResolveAll`?

Answer (score 2):

It was done this way so that you can have a [Composite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).

An example Composite `IService`

```
public class CompositeDataService : IService
{
    public readonly IService[] services;

    public CompositeDataService(IService[] services)
    {
        this.services = services;
    }
}
```

And a demonstration test

```
[Fact]
public void Test()
{
    var container = new UnityContainer();

    container.RegisterType<IService, CompositeDataService>();
    container.RegisterType<IService, LoggingService>("Logging");
    container.RegisterType<IService, CachingService>("Caching");

    var service = container.Resolve<IService>();

    Assert.IsType<CompositeDataService>(service);
    Assert.Equal(2, ((CompositeDataService)service).services.Count());
}
```

---

It is officially documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660852(v=pandp.20).aspx)

> The two overloads of this method [`ResolveAll`] accept either an interface or a type name, and they return an instance of `IEnumerable` that contains references to all registered objects of that type that are **not** default mappings. The list returned by the `ResolveAll` method contains only named instance registrations. The `ResolveAll` method is useful if you have registered multiple object or interface types using the same type but different names

---

[Here](http://tecx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/TecX/TecX.Unity/Mapping/Remember.cs) is some code to work around it (**Note: I haven't run the code**)

```
using System;

using Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;

public class Remember : UnityContainerExtension
{
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        this.Context.Registering += this.OnRegistering;
        this.Context.RegisteringInstance += this.OnRegisteringInstance;
    }

    private void OnRegisteringInstance(object sender, RegisterInstanceEventArgs e)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Name))
        {
            string uniqueName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            this.Context.RegisterNamedType(e.RegisteredType, uniqueName);

            this.Context.Policies.Set<IBuildKeyMappingPolicy>(
                new BuildKeyMappingPolicy(new NamedTypeBuildKey(e.RegisteredType)), 
                new NamedTypeBuildKey(e.RegisteredType, uniqueName));
        }
    }

    private void OnRegistering(object sender, RegisterEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.TypeFrom != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Name))
        {
            string uniqueName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            this.Context.RegisterNamedType(e.TypeFrom, uniqueName);

            if (e.TypeFrom.IsGenericTypeDefinition && e.TypeTo.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
            {
                this.Context.Policies.Set<IBuildKeyMappingPolicy>(
                    new GenericTypeBuildKeyMappingPolicy(new NamedTypeBuildKey(e.TypeTo)),
                    new NamedTypeBuildKey(e.TypeFrom, uniqueName));
            }
            else
            {
                this.Context.Policies.Set<IBuildKeyMappingPolicy>(
                    new BuildKeyMappingPolicy(new NamedTypeBuildKey(e.TypeTo)),
                    new NamedTypeBuildKey(e.TypeFrom, uniqueName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With an [example](http://tecx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/TecX/TecX.Unity.Test/RememberFixture.cs)

```
[TestMethod]
public void CanResolveMultipeDefaultMappingsUsingResolveAll()
{
    var container = new UnityContainer().AddNewExtension<Remember>();

    container.RegisterType<IFoo, One>();
    container.RegisterType<IFoo, Two>();
    container.RegisterType<IFoo, Three>();

    IFoo[] foos = container.ResolveAll<IFoo>().OrderBy(f => f.GetType().Name).ToArray();

    Assert.AreEqual(3, foos.Length);
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(foos[0], typeof(One));
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(foos[1], typeof(Three));
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(foos[2], typeof(Two));
}
```